# Select real-time exchange rates for one currency pair from Yahoo

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm using this API link:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDEUR%22,%20%22USDJPY%22,%20%22USDBGN%22,%20%22USDCZK%22,%20%22USDDKK%22,%20%22USDGBP%22,%20%22USDHUF%22,%20%22USDLTL%22,%20%22USDLVL%22,%20%22USDPLN%22,%20%22USDRON%22,%20%22USDSEK%22,%20%22USDCHF%22,%20%22USDNOK%22,%20%22USDHRK%22,%20%22USDRUB%22,%20%22USDTRY%22,%20%22USDAUD%22,%20%22USDBRL%22,%20%22USDCAD%22,%20%22USDCNY%22,%20%22USDHKD%22,%20%22USDIDR%22,%20%22USDILS%22,%20%22USDINR%22,%20%22USDKRW%22,%20%22USDMXN%22,%20%22USDMYR%22,%20%22USDNZD%22,%20%22USDPHP%22,%20%22USDSGD%22,%20%22USDTHB%22,%20%22USDZAR%22,%20%22USDISK%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

But it seems this is not the way to select an element with a specific id.

So check the link and my problem is that inside results - > rate elements are with different id so for now i want only USDEUR index and i tried something like that

```
<script>
            setInterval(function(){ 
                //somehow convert xml to json
                $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDEUR%22,%20%22USDJPY%22,%20%22USDBGN%22,%20%22USDCZK%22,%20%22USDDKK%22,%20%22USDGBP%22,%20%22USDHUF%22,%20%22USDLTL%22,%20%22USDLVL%22,%20%22USDPLN%22,%20%22USDRON%22,%20%22USDSEK%22,%20%22USDCHF%22,%20%22USDNOK%22,%20%22USDHRK%22,%20%22USDRUB%22,%20%22USDTRY%22,%20%22USDAUD%22,%20%22USDBRL%22,%20%22USDCAD%22,%20%22USDCNY%22,%20%22USDHKD%22,%20%22USDIDR%22,%20%22USDILS%22,%20%22USDINR%22,%20%22USDKRW%22,%20%22USDMXN%22,%20%22USDMYR%22,%20%22USDNZD%22,%20%22USDPHP%22,%20%22USDSGD%22,%20%22USDTHB%22,%20%22USDZAR%22,%20%22USDISK%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys', function(data) {
                var USD = 1/data.query.results.rate['USDEUR'].Rate * 1.955
                document.getElementById('output-value').innerHTML = USD * document.getElementById('input-value').value;     
                });
             }, 500);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is easier to understand if you run the URL through a decoder (e.g., PHP's `urldecode()` function, which is what I did, or one of the many decoders available online). The URL is just an encoded version of this:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=
select *
from yahoo.finance.xchange
where pair in ("USDEUR", "USDJPY", "USDBGN", "USDCZK", "USDDKK", 
    "USDGBP", "USDHUF", "USDLTL", "USDLVL", "USDPLN", "USDRON", 
    "USDSEK", "USDCHF", "USDNOK", "USDHRK", "USDRUB", "USDTRY", 
    "USDAUD", "USDBRL", "USDCAD", "USDCNY", "USDHKD", "USDIDR", 
    "USDILS", "USDINR", "USDKRW", "USDMXN", "USDMYR", "USDNZD", 
    "USDPHP", "USDSGD", "USDTHB", "USDZAR", "USDISK")
&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

I added a little formatting to make it obvious what's going on. It's a [YQL (Yahoo! Query Language)](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) statement (effectively just a SQL SELECT statement) with a list of pair names.

**To get your desired result, just remove the other pairs from the URL, like this:**

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDEUR%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

Response (formatted for readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2016-01-26T19:43:48Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <rate id="USDEUR">
            <Name>USD/EUR</Name>
            <Rate>0.9217</Rate>
            <Date>1/26/2016</Date>
            <Time>7:43pm</Time>
            <Ask>0.9218</Ask>
            <Bid>0.9217</Bid>
        </rate>
    </results>
</query>
<!-- total: 14 -->
<!-- main-4f1bf6c6-c3ce-11e5-a05e-56847afe9799 -->
```

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for pointing that out. It's been years since I've used any Yahoo! APIs, and I hadn't heard of this. I updated my answer.